# Probability of a coin being fair from an unkown sample

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, hypothesis-testing

Suppose you have a bag of *n* coins. There a *k* unknown biased coins in the bag and the rest are fair coins, with *k* in the range [0,*n*].

Is it possible to measure the probability that a randomly sampled coin *c* is an unfair coin (without knowing *k*; the total number of biased coins)? Or additionally are there any methods wan reveal any insights this problem?

My intuition is that it's impossible...

Comment: That depends, what is the probability that $k=c$ for a given $c$?

Comment: The probability is $k/n$, so if you don't know $k$ it is impossible to compute this exactly. If you are allowed to sample and flip coins repeatedly (and if you have some other information like the nature of the bias), a Bayesian approach can help.

Comment: If they are real coins they are not perfect, so each one is biased. The question then is how much.